# Total momentum of the Universe

Tags: cosmology, universe, momentum, big-bang

What is the total momentum of the whole Universe in reference to the point in space where the Big Bang took place?

According to my reasoning (and a bit elementary knowledge) it should be exactly equal to 0 since the 'explosion' and scattering of the matter throught the space would not change the total momentum in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no point in space where the big bang took place.  It happened everywhere, simultaneously.  Centered on Earth, since everything is moving away from us with a uniform velocity (or is stationary with respect to the CMB, if you prefer), the net momentum of the universe is approximately zero.

Comment: But you should be cautious about thinking of the big bang as an 'explosion'

Comment: There's a reason why it's not called the big explosion

Comment: @MureyTasroc What is the reason it is not called the Big "Expansion"?